# How can I add an item with icon in the system menu of a form?

Tags: windows, delphi

This is my code that works except for the icon

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var item : TMenuItemInfo;
begin
  with item do
  begin
    cbSize := SizeOf(MenuItemInfo);
    fMask := MIIM_TYPE or MIIM_ID;
    fType := MFT_STRING;
    wID := 180;
    dwTypeData := PChar('Test');
    cch := 4;
    hbmpItem := Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Handle;  //Image1 is TImage
  end;
  InsertMenuItem(GetSystemMenu(Handle, FALSE),0,true,item);
end;
```

Comment: Read [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-menuiteminfoa): `hbmpItem` is only processed when `fMask` includes `MIIM_BITMAP` - you don't set the flags for fun.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of issues:

1. You don't clear the `TMenuItemInfo` instance before use. Unassigned fields may contain invalid or erroneous data when the call is made.

   Use

   `ZeroMemory(@item, SizeOf(item));`

   at the beginning of the procedure.
2. The combination of `fMask` and `fType` members you have is incorrect.

   Use the following instead

   ```
   fMask := MIIM_STRING or MIIM_BITMAP or MIIM_ID;
   //  fType := MFT_STRING;
   ```

   That is, don't assign `fType`

Here is a sample snip of a test, where a `TImage`  holds the  image depicting a number 2 on orange background. That is added as icon to the new menu item. (Which is your question)

[image]

Adding test code as requested:

```
// Note! Your `Image1` must have a bitmap loaded
procedure TForm39.AddSystemMenuItem;
var
  item : TMenuItemInfo;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@item, SizeOf(item));
  with item do
  begin
    cbSize := SizeOf(MenuItemInfo);
    fMask := MIIM_STRING or MIIM_BITMAP or MIIM_ID;
    // fType := MFT_STRING;
    wID := 180;
    dwTypeData := PChar('Test');
    cch := 4;
    hbmpItem := Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Handle;  //Image1 is TImage
  end;
  if not InsertMenuItem(GetSystemMenu(Handle, FALSE),0,true,item) then
    ShowMessage('Failed');
end;

procedure TForm39.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AddSystemMenuItem;
end;
```

Comment: it didn't work.

Comment: Please be more specific. What exactly did not work?

Comment: I applied your recommendation to the letter and it does not work

Comment: Well you asked how to get the icon to the menu item. As you can see from my example it works.

Comment: I don't understand why you post your code in a comment. What do you want to say?

Comment: your code please.

Comment: Its works with a BMP file I put the first time a PNG.
sorry.

Comment: Ok, that explains it. It is indeed a fact that one cannot load a .png image to a `TImage` and then read the same as a `TBitmap`. Such a conversion simply doesn't take place.

Comment: @TomBrunberg Can you please make the example even more foolproof by also using a `TImage` instance which loads from a BMP file? I mean: the documentation doesn't use the term "**bitmap**" for fun either, but then again people cannot distinguish different file formats to begin with. Or read docs.

Comment: @AmigoJack I do understand the reason for your suggestion, so I added a comment in the code block, instead of changing the code that is based on askers code.